# The process cannot access the file "File Name.xls" because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to access an Excel document via a Windows Service.  I have not been able to get the document to open and this is the error I keep getting.

`The process cannot access the file 'C:\PRDBacklog\prd_backlog.xls' because it is being used by another process.:`

I am wondering if there is anything wrong with the way I am accessing it.  This is a 97-03 excel file and I have been able to access other excel files with this code but none that were a 97-03 excel file.

```
string matrixCopyTargetPath = @"C:\PRDBacklog";
string destFilePath = Path.Combine(matrixCopyTargetPath, fileName);
string sourceFilePath = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
// connection string
var cnnStr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0; HDR = YES\";", destFilePath);
var cnn = new OleDbConnection(cnnStr);
// get schema, then data
var dt = new DataTable();

try
{
   File.Copy(sourceFilePath, destFilePath, true);
   cnn.Open();
   var schemaTable = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
   string sql = string.Format("select * from {0}", "Sheet1$"); //Unsure how to access the Table
   var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
   da.Fill(dt);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\kevin_brosam\Desktop\testingExportFromG.txt", true))
   {
   //writer.WriteLine($"0{sheetNames.Count.ToString()}");
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Message))
   writer.WriteLine($"1:{DateTime.Now}: {e.Message}:");
   //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.InnerException.Message))
   //    writer.WriteLine($"2:{DateTime.Now}: {e.InnerException.Message}:");
   //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.InnerException.InnerException.Message))
   //    writer.WriteLine($"3:{DateTime.Now}: {e.InnerException.InnerException.Message}:");
   }
}
finally
{
   // free resources
   cnn.Close();
}
// write out CSV data
using (var wtr = new StreamWriter(csvOutputFile, false)) //Successfully creates new file, except file has no data
{
   foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
   {
      bool firstLine = true;
      foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
      {
         if (!firstLine) { wtr.Write(","); } else { firstLine = false; }
         var data = row[col.ColumnName].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"");
         wtr.Write(string.Format("\"{0}\"", data));
      }
   wtr.WriteLine();
   }
}
```

I am trying to Debug this in a Windows Console for simplicity but I was getting the same error when this was run as a Windows Service.

Comment: It's possible that as you are running as a service, you don't have the correct credentials to write (or read) that file/directory, and this is the best error message available.

Comment: Would I be able to specify the credentials in the Code? I also have been able to access and extract data from different files in this Directory just not a 97-03 excel file.

Comment: Drive changing driver from ACE to JET.  ACE is for Office 2007 and newer.  Jet is for Office 2003.  The 97 is for Win95 which used 16 bit addressing.  WinXP (2003) used 32 bit addressing.  See : https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Comment: Trying ```var cnnStr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0; HDR = Yes; IMEX = 1\";", destFilePath);``` I got the same error.

Comment: try string cnnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
    file.FileName + "; Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;\"";

Comment: @level_zebra Same result as before

Comment: make  sure you target x86 on your project in Visual Studio

Comment: @level_zebra I am not familiar with that. How would I do that?

Comment: right-click on the project (not solution) go to properties. or google it

Comment: @level_zebra Setting x86 results in the same error

Comment: do you have https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920 installed on your machine ? if not, install and try using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Comment: In my experience, this error message generally is dead-on accurate.  That is, there is some other process holding onto this file.  Perhaps a previous test run of Excel that didn't terminate properly or somebody has it open "someplace" if the file happens to be on a shared drive.  Start by checking Task Manager.  If it is a shared disk, you might need IT's help to figure out who is holding it.

Comment: @FrankMerrow is correct.  It's almost impossible to get Excel to unload properly if you are loading it via automation.  Make sure it's really closed by using TaskManager to kill it.

Comment: I have gone through all processes and Task manager and ended all relating to Microsoft office/excel. Upon inspecting the ```var cnn``` in debug mode the ServerVersion is throwing an error ```ServerVersion = 'cnn.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'``` Is this because the connection string is bad or would excel being used cause this.

Comment: So I see in your code you've already started looking at Inner Exceptions.  I would take InvalidOperationException as probably an outer exception and would expect an inner exception with perhaps the "being used" exception.  Can you print out the whole exception stack and post it?  Also, tell us the exact line you are getting the exception at.  Additionally, if your code has changed much . . . perhaps update it.  Also, please indicate if this is a shared drive or not.